# Count of all IFRAME Tags in a page?

Tags: html, iframe

How to calculate the number of iframes used in a web page?
Please provide some pointers.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length
```

Comment: Thanks Marius for the quick help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
alert(iframes);
```

Note: This will not grab inner/nested iframes.

Comment: Thanks Meder for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

`document.frames.length` will also work.  Unfortunately, this property is only available within Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks david for the quick reply.

Comment: @archana joy: No problem, just please be careful with respect to cross browser issues as reported in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.I got the answer.

document.frames.length OR
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length